# How do I export my django model into custom csv?

Tags: python, django, export-to-csv, django-excel

I have a Django app in which I maintain products for a webshop. Since many products have multiple variations and working in Excel is not optimal, I thought Python could help me and make the work easier. However, for the import into my store system I need a CSV file and here comes my problem.

I have a model with five fields where two are multiple fields (django-multiselectfield).

```
SIZES = (('16', 'Size 16'),
              ('17', 'Size 17'),
              ('18', 'Size 18'),
              ('19', 'Size 19'),
              ('20', 'Size 20'))

COLORS = (('white', 'White'),
              ('black', 'Black'),
              ('blue', 'Blue'),
              ('red', 'Red'),
              ('yellow', 'Yellow'))

class Items(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=254, null=True, blank=True, default='',)
    sku = models.CharField(_('SKU'), max_length=254, null=True, blank=True, default='',)
    size = MultiSelectField(_('Size'), choices=SIZES)
    color = MultiSelectField(_('Color'), choices=COLORS)
    price = models.DecimalField(_('Price'), max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
```

I created two products to demonstrate my needs
[image]
In my CSV file, for example, I need a new line for each size and color so that the variation is created correctly in the webshop software.

So my CSV would have to look like this:

```
"type","sku","attribute 1 name","attribute 1 value","attribute 2 name","attribute 2 value"
"variable","abc01921","size","16","color","white,black,blue"
"variation","abc01921_white_16","size","16","color","white"
"variation","abc01921_black_16","size","16","color","black"
"variation","abc01921_blue_16","size","16","color","blue"
"variable","abc01831","size","16,17","color","black,blue"
"variation","abc01831_black_16","size","16","color","black"
"variation","abc01831_blue_16","size","16","color","blue"
"variation","abc01831_black_17","size","17","color","black"
"variation","abc01831_blue_17","size","17","color","blue"
```

[image]

How do I best implement this successfully? How can I check if it is a variable or a variation and use this information to write the CSV line into the file accordingly?

Comment: I don't know all details of your project, but according `I thought Python could help me and make the work easier` may decide that using of [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) will be more flexible and simple. At least pandas is developed to do data analysis and conversion tasks easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand correctly you have to generate CSV file from Django database values?

To be able reproduce code without real Django model I created `Item` that has same fields as your model. CSV generation code should work for Django real model objects as is (mostly... I'm not sure how model return `MultiSelectField` values).

Create list of example item objects:

```py
class Item:
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        self.name = kw['name']
        self.sku = kw['sku']
        self.size = kw['size']
        self.color = kw['color']
        self.price = kw['price']


items = [
    Item(
        **{
            'name': 'product1',
            'sku': 'abc123',
            'size': ('16', '17'),
            'color': ('green', 'orange'),
            'price': 123
        }
    ),
    Item(
        **{
            'name': 'product2',
            'sku': 'abc321',
            'size': ('61', '71'),
            'color': ('yellow', 'red'),
            'price': 321
        }
    ),
]
```

Write csv file with all items:

```py
header = ["type", "sku", "attribute 1 name", "attribute 1 value", "attribute 2 name", "attribute 2 value"]
csv_lines = [header]

for item in items:
    csv_lines.append(['variable', item.sku, 'size', ','.join(item.size), 'color', ','.join(item.color)])
    for size_variation in item.size:
        for color_variation in item.color:
            csv_lines.append(['variation', f'{item.sku}_{color_variation}_{size_variation}', 'size', size_variation, 'color', color_variation])


import csv


with open('./csv_file_to_import.csv', 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
    write = csv.writer(csv_file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    write.writerows(csv_lines)
```

Check csv resulted file:

```
"type","sku","attribute 1 name","attribute 1 value","attribute 2 name","attribute 2 value"
"variable","abc123","size","16,17","color","green,orange"
"variation","abc123_green_16","size","16","color","green"
"variation","abc123_orange_16","size","16","color","orange"
"variation","abc123_green_17","size","17","color","green"
"variation","abc123_orange_17","size","17","color","orange"
"variable","abc321","size","61,71","color","yellow,red"
"variation","abc321_yellow_61","size","61","color","yellow"
"variation","abc321_red_61","size","61","color","red"
"variation","abc321_yellow_71","size","71","color","yellow"
"variation","abc321_red_71","size","71","color","red"
```

If users of you Django app don't have access to Django server storage you should make CSV file downloadable via browser instead of save it to disk. @DarkDrifterX99 already [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70781063/13946204) how to implement CSV response

Answer (score 0):

> I have a model with five fields where two are multiple fields (django-multiselectfield)

> I need a new line for each size and color so that the variation is created correctly in the webshop software.

I would assume each Product DB entry would be a "variable" and then the "variations" would be manually created when [writing to the CSV for each count of the two multiselect fields.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/outputting-csv/#using-the-python-csv-library)